# ESP8266 gives garbage using Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am using ESP8266 board connected to Arduino Nano using this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdGFzLANsd4). But every time I switch on the board, I get garbage values like this "¤HlzGà". It changes each time I switch on and off.

I tried using different baud rate and ESP8266 board. But I am getting the same results. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: What Baud Rate are you using? I believe it should be 115200

Comment: Which module are you using? When did you buy it? What baud rate are you using? What platform are you on (win,mac,ubuntu)?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of possible reasons why your ESP8266 is returning "garbage" values via serial:

1. During boot of the ESP8266 (before the welcome message is displayed) the baud rate is set to 76800 before being set to the default baud rate of your firmware (note I do not know what firmware you are running, there are many floating about right now). This is normal! You will know if your ESP8266 has successfully booted if you receive a welcome message (which varies with firmware).
2. You have not selected the correct baud rate to communicate with your ESP8266. There are three common baud rates being used presently after the ESP8266 boots (i.e. set just prior to the welcome message), 9600, 115200, and 57600.

For your particular case I strongly suspect that your power supply does not have enough power to power the ESP8266, this is especially true if you are trying to power it from the Arduino Nano's 3.3V supply. In most cases you will need a separate 3.3V power source for your ESP8266. I suspect you are seeing the ESP8266 boot (i.e. showing it's "garbage" during boot sequnce) then the module is shutting off shortly after and becoming unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

When using platformio, I found out that ***if*** I put in my `main.cpp` the following line:

```
Serial.begin(115200)
```

I get garbage.  Baud-rate of `9600` was fine, until I tried a different value, then nothing worked.
I found another entry in `platformio.ini`:

```
monitor_speed = 115200
```

and unless I *matched* these, it got garbage characters.  I can only assume default worked originally, then broke when I set it explicit.  I can also only assume that the Arduino IDE probably has a settings for the serial monitor window as well that needs to match whatever you set in your `main.cpp`.